# Pooling Averages vs. Single Averages

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we have a large dataset that contains information about students in a school, including their "Gender", whether they wear "Glasses", and whether they "Passed" a certain exam.

Using this data, we calculate the following probabilities:

- The probability of passing the exam in the entire student population is p1
- The probability of passing the exam for male students is p2
- The probability of passing the exam for female students is p3
- The probability of passing the exam for students who wear glasses is p4
- The probability of passing the exam for students who do not wear glasses is p5
- The probability of passing the exam for male students who wear glasses is p6
- The probability of passing the exam for female students who wear glasses is p7
- The probability of passing the exam for male students who do not wear glasses is p8
- The probability of passing the exam for female students who do not wear glasses is p9

**Now, imagine we have a new student who is male and does not wear glasses. What is the probability that he will pass the exam?**

The obvious answer to this question seems like the probability is p8 (the probability of passing the exam for male students who do not wear glasses). But after thinking about this for a while, I had the following ideas:

- What if the probability of passing the exam is significantly more influenced by some variable that is not measured in this dataset (e.g. the student's previous grades)?
- What if some of these subsets have a very small population? (e.g. suppose only 1% of all data is male students who do not wear glasses)
- Suppose male students who do not wear glasses generally have lower grades, but this particular student has very good grades - the probability of him passing the exam might be closer to that of some other subgroup?

For such cases, I thought that it might be better to try and "average out" this information to safeguard against possible risks. For example - perhaps the probability that this student will pass the exam is: (p1 + p2 + p5 + p8)/4 ?

This way, we have taken into consideration hidden trends and patterns within the entire student population, the entire population of male students, and the entire population of students who do not wear glasses. The effects and skewness from possible outliers should now have been more smoothened out?

From my Algebra classes, I know that there is no guarantee that p8 must equal to (p1 + p2 + p5 + p8)/4. This brings me to my question:

- **In the absence of any other information and prior knowledge about the exam and the students taking it - is it possible that (p1 + p2 + p5 + p8)/4 might be a "less risky" estimate compared to p8 alone?**
- **Is this a valid estimation procedure, or have I misunderstood how averages and pooled averages are intended to be interpreted and used?**

Thanks!

Note 1: Of course the drawback to this pooled approach is that if there are no outliers in the data, then p8 (the probability of passing the exam for male students who do not wear glasses) would have been a more accurate estimate and we put ourselves in a worse position by pooling the averages.

Note 2: If we did in fact have some prior knowledge, it could have been interesting to take a "weighted pooled average" of the probabilities. For example, if we had information about the student's previous grades, we could give more weight to the probability for the entire student population (p1) or the probability for male students (p2), depending on the relationship between grades and exam performance. However, in the absence of prior knowledge and additional information, it looks like we have no choice but to assume equal weighting.

Comment: Data isn't predictive on its own.  You can design a model that fits the data and you can use that to make predictions, but of course your model might be wrong.  A standard thing is to divide your data into multiple pools...calibrate the model with one pool and test your model against some of the other pools.  Not much you can do without "clean" data to test with.

Comment: Of course, even with the single pool, you could try to test for significance.  Depends on your sample size of course.  But try the neutral hypothesis (none of your variables are significant) and test whether the observed data is plausible.